# How to create a contact record with customer field set as contact or account

Tags: dynamics-crm, contacts, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-webapi

I am trying to create a contact record with its customer set to Account/Contact where customer records are pre-existing.

Here is the request that I am trying.

```
POST <service>/api/data/v8.0/contacts

{

'lastname':’contact1’,

'parentcustomerid_contact': '/contacts(f797401d-64c9-e711-8125-000d3a22f66f)'

}
```

I also tried providing full url of the contact record, but that is also not working. Appreciate any help with correct query or any document that I shall go through to get this scenario working.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use like this `parentcustomerid_contact@odata.bind` to bind single valued navigation properties.

> you must use the @odata.bind annotation to set the value of a single-valued navigation property.

[Read more](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt607875#Associate%20entities%20on%20update)